# Close Android App programatically in Xamarin Forms project

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am using the following code to close the android app in a Xamarin Form project.

`var activity = (Activity)Forms.Context;
activity.FinishAndRemoveTask();`

It is closing the app but if again I tap on the app it is not opening the new instance of the app as the I can see debugger is still active .

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

> it is not opening the new instance of the app as the I can see debugger is still active

When you use `activity.FinishAndRemoveTask()` method, this method cant kill your Android app, it just means :

> Finishes all activities in this task and removes it from the recent tasks list.

You could use the following code to implement this feature :

```
FinishAndRemoveTask();
Java.Lang.JavaSystem.Exit(0);// Terminate JVM
```